# Gulp task with iterator only runs first iteration and then moves on to next task

Tags: css, sass, gulp

My "styles" task only runs the first iteration "editor" and will not run the subsequent iterations. I think this is due to recently updating to Gulp 4.x if that's the case what is the new syntax for this task?

This task used to compile [ 'editor.scss', 'login.scss' , 'main.scss' , 'typography.scss' ] into [ 'editor.css', 'login.css' , 'main.css' , 'typography.css' ]

```
gulp.task('styles', function(){

    for( var i=0, files=[ 'editor', 'login' , 'main' , 'typography' ]; i < files.length; i++ ){

        //Compile Main Styles
        return gulp.src('scss/' + files[i] + '.scss')
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(glob())
            .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error' , sass.logError ) )
            .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer ]))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    }
});
```

Comment: Please take a look to the answers and don't forget to `upvote` and to `validate` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@johannchopin is absolutely correct (and I upvoted).  But if you prefer to stay with the style you have you can use:

```
gulp.task('styles', function () {

  let stream;

  for( var i=0, files=[ 'editor', 'login' , 'main' , 'typography' ]; i < files.length; i++ ){

      //Compile Main Styles
      stream = gulp.src('scss/' + files[i] + '.scss')
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(glob())
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }).on('error' , sass.logError ) )
        .pipe(postcss([ autoprefixer ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css/'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  }

  return stream;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here come from your `return` statement that will quit the for loop. Gulp support directly array:

```js
gulp.task('styles', function(){
  return gulp.src(['/scss/editor.scss', '/scss/login.scss', ...], { base: '.' })
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'));
});
```